# Music Nav Doesn't Work After Installing IntelliType

Tags: windows, keyboard, itunes, intellitype

I have started using a Microsoft Sidewinder X4 Keyboard. It came with the Microsoft IntelliType Pro software. Since I have installed the software I am not able to change my music via the play | previous | next buttons at the top of the keyboard. I use iTunes and not Windows Media Player.

How do I solve this issue?

Here is a screenshot of the Keyboard Properties:

[image: MS IntelliType Pro Screenshot]

Note: I am on Windows 8 using iTunes 11. Uninstalling the IntelliType software is *not* an option as I use the macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an [updated version of the software](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=26950).

I also found [one other option](http://andy.hillhome.org/blog/code/ituneskeys/) that assisted in solving this issue. It involved installing a custom program to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing a little standalone .exe called [MediaKeys](http://blog.skrenes.com/post/11783385993/mediakeys).