# How to make Microsoft IntelliType work with iTunes 11?

Tags: itunes, intellitype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Music Nav Doesn’t Work After Installing IntelliType](https://superuser.com/questions/520275/music-nav-doesnt-work-after-installing-intellitype)

After upgrading to iTunes 11 the previous/next and play/pause keys stopped working with IntelliType 8.2. Keyboard is a "Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000" although I suppose this is not relevant.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing a little standalone .exe called [MediaKeys](http://blog.skrenes.com/post/11783385993/mediakeys).